# Gnome Sudoku doesn't have the features described on the site

Tags: gnome, games

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.2.

I have the latest version of gnome-sudoku and it works fine.

Except the game as I see it doesn't match the description on https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-sudoku/stable/.

The description mentions settings, highlighting, hints,... I don't have these features.

Is there something I can do to activate them?

I really like Gnome-Sudoku and I find it is one of the best Sudoku game available. It would be great to be able to play the "improved" version.